python (Apply inflation table to sales table)
I have the below tables:
Sales Table:
enter image description here
Inflation Table:
enter image description here
I want python to update table one values by multiply each value in table one with inflation in the table 2 depending on the country name and year.
The resulted table will be:
enter image description here
The resulted table will be:
enter image description here

You should be able to tun sales.mul(inflation) or sales*inflation, just make sure to first convert from strings to integers

What is the best code to update all of the first table values?
